# Fix Three.js model when scale hasn't been applied in Blender

Tags: three.js, blender

I built a .glb viewer with Three.js. Whenever I want to display a model from Blender where the scale has not been applied before exporting (e.g. scale at 0.5 instead of 1), I get sizing issues in Three.js. It usually manifests in the model appearing smaller than its bounding box.

Is there a way to get consistent scale with Three.js?

**Downloadable files:**

This is the file that causes the problem:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fotura3d-dev.appspot.com/o/cassette.glb?alt=media&token=27e08f59-68b4-4011-89a4-04bdc56365db

This is the file with transforms applied in Blender which works as expected in Three.js:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fotura3d-dev.appspot.com/o/cassetteApplied.glb?alt=media&token=fc6decb1-aa36-4ab2-8582-9ce21111585b

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the model of your screenshot?

Comment: Sure thing! I just edited the question.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of scene.add(yourModel) ing your model to the scene.. try scene.attach(yourModel)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: You can force recompution of bounding box using mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()

Comment: No change so far. No matter if I recompute for the parent object or the mesh. It always comes out as in the image above.

Comment: If you drag your file onto don mccurdys viewer do you see the same issue:

https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Comment: I can't see the bounding box in the viewer but both files load at different initial sizes. I assumes that means that the problem is happening there, too.